# What regex pattern can I use to match this string?

Tags: c#, regex

What regex pattern can I use to match the following:

Dxx-xxxx/xxx

So:
 - Any string that starts with character 'D'
 - Has any number of any character between the 'D' and the '-'
 - Has any number of any character between the '-' and the '/'
 - Has any number of any character after the '/'

Apologies if I haven't explained this very well!

Comment: A simple enough task. Where are you stuck?

Comment: looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is so difficult on `D.*-.*/.*`?

If you want to ensure that there is at least one character for behind the `D`, `-` and `/` respectivly you should use `.+` instead of those `.*`.